# My wallet is making transactions to bubblegum without my permission

Tags: security

I recently noticed that one of my phantom solana wallets was making daily transactions with Bubblegum. I want to know if this is normal or if I should just delete my wallet.
Here is one of the transactions.
https://solscan.io/tx/doVARWFZxo22XUTm8rJCWaxjFH7Njb2RGNL9C1U37DqSbZhW1vrxC5yDMUn7R1kAMJZQ55oPqvim6e81Dj8Tia5
My wallet is 5K3b3Qp4Ag2p8CCo4fksSv2AqUpCd2Pq74yiVswh84xK
Am I hacked? This happened after interacting with CWIF Token on birdeye. I was airdropped it and thought it would be ok to just sell it to get rid of it. I didnt think doing so would put me at risk. I am not worried about my funds as I have already removed them. Just want to get to the bottom of this and maybe warn others of this malicious activity.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Bubblegum program is used to distribute cNFTs. These transactions are not initiated by your wallet, but rather someone else is sending you some NFTs. You can see that the signer/payer is another wallet, `6H4t7LCyFqvWpPouihorUwMahkWHeKGUPRwo8be9E4wa`, and not yours.

These transactions do not mean that you have been hacked.

On Solana, there is no consent when receiving assets so this is not something you can stop. Some projects simply scan the chain for accounts that meet certain criteria and airdrop them other stuff.

That particular transaction is sending you a 3D DRiP Devil NFT. Not all explorers fully supported cNFTs yet but you can see this one on [XRay](https://xray.helius.xyz/token/4fT3ZeKj6Zu9TtTarvDrj61bgGtLBShpc9vz8swrcGHM?network=mainnet). You may want to check your [DRiP](https://drip.haus/) account to find out more info.